# Jquery slideToggle() acting weird on touch screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am using JQuery to slide toggle a navigation bar when a div is pressed.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".menu-toggle").click(function() {
        $(".nav").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="menu-toggle">Toggle Menu</div>
<nav class="sidebar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

This works well on desktop, but when using a touch screen (i.e. smartphone) it acts up. When you press the .menu-toggle button, the .nav toggles up and down as expected. But when you scroll the page with your finger the .nav hides itself. It doesn't slide toggle back up, it just "disappears" and you have to press the .menu-toggle button again to display it again.

How can I go about fixing this so when a user scrolls down the page with a touch screen, the .nav doesn't hide itself automatically?

EDIT: Here's the actually code

HTML:

```
<div class="resized-menu">
    Toggle Menu
</div>
<nav class="main-nav">
    <div class="inner-wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".resized-menu").click(function() {
        $(".main-nav").slideToggle();
    });
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    //hide/show main navigation when window is resized
    if($(window).width() >= 550) {
        $(".main-nav").show();
        $(".sidebar").show();
    } else {
        $(".main-nav").hide();
        $(".sidebar").show();
    }
});
```

Main CSS:

```
.resized-menu {
    font-size: 3em;
    background: #222;
    color: #FFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    padding: 3px 0px;
}

.main-nav {
    height: 40px;
    background: url("../img/main-nav-bg.png");
    font-size: 12px;
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    display: block;
}

.main-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    /*margin: 0 0 0 123px;*/
    padding: 0;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.main-nav ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 16.666%;
    text-align: center;
}

.main-nav li a {
    display: block;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 7px 15px; /*0px 15px*/
    /*line-height: 40px;*/
    height: 40px;
    transition: .2s linear;
    border-left: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}
```

CSS with "only screen and (max-width:550px)":

```
.resized-menu {
    display: block;
}

.main-nav {
    height: 100%;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    display: none;
}

.main-nav ul li {
    width: 50%;
    border: none;
}

.main-nav li a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    border-top: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code on an iPhone in Safari and Chrome and it is working fine.
I don't know what is causing this problem, may be it'll help if you post your entire code. 
By the way the nav selector in jQuery should be $("nav").slideToggle() without the dot because you're selecting an element not a class.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! I've added the actual code to the OP.

Comment: I want to see you actual jQuery code, because this one is not working.

Comment: It's working fine, some mobile browsers if you pull the page down it will refresh the page, I think this is what is happening to you. 
try to add this to css code to disable the horizontal scroll : 
  html, body {
    overflow-y:hidden;
    height:100% ;
  }

Comment: Ok, so I've found the problem. I had a bit of jquery somewhere else that I used for resizing that was affecting it (I've edited my main post to show the code). Now I need a solution to keep that functionality and fix my problem!

Comment: Where is your main-nav class in HTML ??

Comment: Wow, I am soo sorry. I included the wrong html code. This is embarrassing. Hopefully everything is ok now. I apologize for wasting your time like this.

Comment: I've tried your code on my mobile and it's working fine!
I don't understand your code, how do you differentiate between these two css files? You should use media queries! 
Does your problem occur on a mobile device or on a laptop with a touch screen? 
Does your problem occur in the first CSS file or in the second ?

Comment: Like I said in my previous comment, it seems to be a jquery problem. Whenever you scroll on a touch screen, jquery seems to think I'm resizing the screen, thus hiding the menu (because that's what the code tells it to do).

Comment: Where is sidebar class in the actual HTML code?? 
You are selecting it  in your jQuery code but there is no such class in your HTML code! 
Why are you showing both sidebar and the main-nav if the window width more than 550 ??? check your jQuery code I think this is a mistake and you should show only main-nav class.